# Testing unimplemented method in abstract class

Tags: java, junit, abstract-class, mockito

I have an abstract class, say `AbstractClass` where I've got a public void method `myMethod` without an implementation. While I'm testing this class, I've created an anonymous subclass, where I can implement `myMethod` as I see fit.
In `AbstractClass` There's another method, say `myImplementedMethod` which calls `myMethod`. Is there a trick to what I can put in `myMethod` in the anonymous subclass, so as to be able to verify that it has been called?

Edit:
I'm using Mockito for mocking, and it is not my place to use another framework.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract void myMethod();

    public void myImplementedMethod() {
        myMethod();
}

public class AbstractClassTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        AbstractClass myClass = new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            public void myMethod(){
                //What could I put here?
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyImplementedMethod() {
        myClass.myImplementedMethod();
        //check that myMethod is called.
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at mocking frameworks.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Mockito

Comment: Then check to make sure it's called. The subclass can't even compile if it doesn't exist. What specifically are you trying to test?

Comment: How would I check that it's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mockito's spy works for you, great. However I don't believe it will capture internal method calls. How about the below...

```
public class AbstractClassTest {

 boolean methodCalled = false;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    methodCalled = false;
    AbstractClass myClass = new AbstractClass() {

        @Override
        public void myMethod(){
            methodCalled = true;
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testMyImplementedMethod() {
    assertFalse(methodCalled);
    myClass.myImplementedMethod();
    assertTrue(methodCalled);
}
}
```

Comment: Good answer. This was the kind of elegance I was hoping for, especially since the use of Mockito's spy is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a spy object on your descendant class, call the implemented method and later ensure the not implemented one was called with `verify`

```
AbstractClass myInstance= Mockito.spy(myClass);
myInstance.myImplementedMethod();
Mockito.verify(myInstance).myMethod();
```

Comment: I don't believe a spy will work. I believe a spy can only verify external calls to methods not internal calls.

Comment: Spy is for mocking a real object, of course is not going to do the work. What really does the work is verify() which ensures that myMethod was called on myInstance. Honestly, I really think this is the right way, your solution is like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm open to your solution as well. I'd just also like to know why the use of a spy, which according to the Mockito documentation is somewhat discouraged, is justified?

Comment: I agree with the reason that spies should be used carefully, but there are situations i which i find them necessary, for example when working with third party or legacy code. In your case you have full control to modify your descendant class (you even created a class only for testing) but that may be not the case in some other situations

Comment: You are right. The docs are not explicit about this but tried it out and it does work.

Answer (score 2):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class AbstractClassTest {

    private AbstractClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        AbstractClass instance = new AbstractClass() {
            @Override
            public void myMethod(){}
        }
        myClass = spy(instance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyImplementedMethod() {
        myClass.myImplementedMethod();
        verify(myClass).myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe a spy will work. I believe a spy can only verify external calls to methods not internal calls.

Comment: If you don't believe you can check it and reads doc for mockito. If my answer are not true. don't hesitate down vote for my answer.

Comment: You are right. The docs are not explicit about this but tried it out and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the reflection api like this

```
YourClass.getClass().getMethod("myMethod").invoke(obj,args);  // pass the appropriate parameters
```

and if this throws an exception then you havent implemented the method.
I didnt try this myself , if it works do comment .